# How to change a TextView's text by pressing a Button in Android widget

Tags: android, widget, android-pendingintent

Here is my res/xml/widget.xml

```
  <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="+" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-" />
```

here is my AppWidgetProvider file:

```
 @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button,pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,views);

//            views.setTextViewText(R.id.textView,"2");
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);


        }
    }
```

Press button(+) then, textview adding one \textview=6. press button(-) then, textview = 4
Please help me, I need any solution.

Comment: I don't understand how to use pending intent in change textview? Please help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement View.OnClickListener in your Activity/Fragment.
2. Create a static integer count. `private static int count;`
3. Add the following logic in your Activity/Fragment:

   ```
       Button buttonPlus = findViewById(R.id.button);
       Button buttonMinus = findViewById(R.id.button3);
       textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

       if (textView.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
           count = 0;
       } else {
           count = Integer.valueOf(textView.getText().toString());
       }

       buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(this);
       buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```
4. Within your implemented onClick, add the following:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
           case R.id.button:
               count++;
               updateTextView(count);
               break;
           case R.id.button3:
               count--;
               updateTextView(count);
               break;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Finally create a method that updates your textview:

   ```
   private void updateTextView(int count) {
       textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but my activity is extend AppWidgetProvider. Activity have not  findViewById() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly dereference views from **`AppWidgetProvider`**, You have to use **`Remote Views`** for that.
Example:-

```
private static final String MyOnClick = "Button OnClick";

RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.you_widget_layout);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.your_button, MyOnClick);
```

Get You Button Click Listener Like This:-

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
   if (intent.getAction().equals(MyOnClick)) //Update Here <- <-
   {
     views.setTextViewText(R.id.your_text_view, "text here");
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe, my wrong. error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to PendingIntent